# CI/CD Pipeline for Web App that Publishes with "Merge all outputs to a Single Assembly"

Tags: visual-studio, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I've been working with Microsoft to get a CI/CD Pipeline working and finally got everything to Build and Deploy as expected, with one important piece missing:

Previously, we manually Published to a File System and in the Setting of the Publishing Profile, in the File Publish Options > Precompile during Publishing is checked and the Configure/Advanced Precompile Settings, we have Merge all outputs to a single assembly checked, with the file name ourProduct.dll that Publish places in the Bin folder of the precompiled output. So from there, we manually copy everything in the PreCompiledOutput folder and paste it into a target server's appropriate directory, and all old files are replaced with the new ones.

Our CI/CD Pipeline does everything mentioned above only WITHOUT the 
ourProduct.dll being created and placed in the Bin folder - useless.

Here's the MS Build Arguments for the Build Defiition's Build solution step:
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true  /p:PublishProfile="CompiledOutput" /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\" /p:OutDir="$(build.binariesdirectory)\"

"CompiledOutput" is the name of the publishing profile

BTW, we're using VisualStudio 2017 with VSTS.

We are SO close - any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try passing the MSBuild flag `/p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true`?

Comment: By the way, it's not "useless" without precompilation. If it's not precompiled, compilation will happen after deployment when the application is first loaded.

Comment: Is it a website project? How do you specify solution/project in Solution input box of Visual Studio Build task?

Comment: @DanielMann - Thanks for the tip, I added that and now change, still no DLL when compiled, and it was precompiling previously without it. Also, when I said useless, I meant for our purposes we need that DLL not only for the web app but for the services we have running elsewhere.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT - I do not/did not have a Build task in VS, I only started using MSBuild arguments with the VSTS Build definition. This is a Web App project and when Building previously, just used the Build menu option above the Publish menu option in the Project's right-click menu. Not being able to indicate the file name or even Merge all outputs to a single assembly is what I believe is holding me back, even though we're pointing to the Publishing Profile. Maybe I'm not referring to it properly?

Comment: Try to specify  /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\" msbuild argument instead and check the result. On the other hand, can you share the simple sample on the OneDrive that can reproduce this issue?

Comment: Sorry for not replying for so long! I have worked with 3 different teams at Micorosft, and everything they have suggested has not succeeded, including many of the suggestions you all have made. They are able to have success with a new MVC application, but with a legacy, migrated web forms app, no success.